# Selenium Page object model

Tags: automated-testing

Can anyone guide me to automate an E-commerce website using page object model in selenium?

I have any idea about page object model but don't know from where to start.

Comment: Hi Vineesha. Our question is quite broad. Please, share your approach and ask for specific advice on refactoring on the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Reading your questions I want to clarify a couple of things.

Are you looking for an e-commerce site that is suitable for practising POM with selenium tests?

Or are you looking for a tutorial on how to test an e-commerce site using POM with selenium tests?

Here is a demo e-commerce site specifically designed to practice writing selenium tests. 
http://automationpractice.com/index.php

The site is not very challenging to automate, common elements have id's, there aren't many iframes that I've found, writing custom xpaths for elements which do not have id's is pretty straight forward as all elements are tagged and named in a meaningful way.

Once you have automated a few tests I would suggest looking at 
https://www.utest.com/articles/best-websites-to-practice-test-automation-using-selenium-webdriver

The utest article has a selection of sites that are more challenging to automate, for example, iframes, drag and drop, scrolling, slow loading elements etc.

If you are are looking for a tutorial on POM with selenium there are quite a few on youtube.